# Clothes snap cover

Tags: clothing

I'm not sure if this is the right site to put this on, so if there is a better place to ask this, please let me know.

I wear overalls and keep my phone in the chest pocket. My problem is that the male part of the snap inside the pocket is scratching the phone. Is there anything I can do to fix this? I've thought about cutting it out and putting a denim patch over it, but I would rather not cut it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick some spacers in the sides of the pocket to hold it open.  Then spread a thin layer of silicone caulk over the back of the snap, extending a little onto the surrounding fabric.  Give it at least a few hours to cure (or the time specified on the container), before removing the spacers.  I'd wait until the next day for it to fully cure before using it.  It will survive washing the overalls once it's cured, won't rub off, and will prevent scratching the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Another gluing approach is to get (solvent-based, not PVA) fabric glue, and glue a patch on the inside.  Get plenty of glue on the patch, but much less (try none at all at first) on the garment as too much will soak through.  As in Fixer1234's answer, you'll need to hold the pocket open.  Follow the instructions on the glue, but it might need to dry until it's tacky before pressing the patch onto the back of the fabric, covering the snap.

If the pocket is big enough you could even use iron-on hemming tape, but it probably isn't.

Answer (score 1):

A less chemically based approach: Instead of cutting it out and patching it, just sew a small (denim) patch on the inside of the pocket over the backside of the snap.

Comment: Or trim an iron-on patch to a good size.  It won't adhere to the snap -- it will adhere to the fabric around the patch.  I think the iron-on patch is the quickest and simplest approach.